# The website with id 8 that was requested wasn't found. Verify the website and try again

Tags: magento2.4.5p1

I have multi-store website, And I am getting an error while add customer address from admin side. It is working fine with store id 1 and website id 1. It is not working for store id 8 and website id 2.
[image]

**I'm getting this error**

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): The website with id 8 that was requested wasn't found. Verify the website and try again.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debuging I found a solution, I have changed from `SCOPE_WEBSITE` to `SCOPE_STORE` the in this file line no. 131

> File path
> :vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/ResourceModel/Address/Attribute/Source/CountryWithWebsites.php

**Piece of code**

```
public function getAllOptions($withEmpty = true, $defaultValues = false)
    {
        if (!$this->options) {
            $websiteIds = [];

            if (!$this->shareConfig->isGlobalScope()) {
                $allowedCountries = [];

                foreach ($this->storeManager->getWebsites() as $website) {
                    $countries = $this->allowedCountriesReader
                        ->getAllowedCountries(ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE, $website->getId());
                    $allowedCountries[] = $countries;

                    foreach ($countries as $countryCode) {
                        $websiteIds[$countryCode][] = $website->getId();
                    }
                }

                $allowedCountries = array_unique(array_merge([], ...$allowedCountries));
            } else {
                // Address can be added only for the allowed country list.
                $storeId = null;
                $customerId = $this->request->getParam('parent_id') ?? null;
                if ($customerId) {
                    $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
                    $storeId = $customer->getStoreId();
                }

                $allowedCountries = $this->allowedCountriesReader->getAllowedCountries(
                    ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
                    $storeId
                );
            }

            $this->options = $this->createCountriesCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('country_id', ['in' => $allowedCountries])
                ->toOptionArray();

            foreach ($this->options as &$option) {
                if (isset($websiteIds[$option['value']])) {
                    $option['website_ids'] = $websiteIds[$option['value']];
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->options;
    }
```

**Replace from:-**

```
$allowedCountries = $this->allowedCountriesReader->getAllowedCountries(
                    ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
                    $storeId
                );
```

**Replace to:-**

```
$allowedCountries = $this->allowedCountriesReader->getAllowedCountries(
    ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
    $storeId
);
```

Seems to core issue

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a value in the `core_config_data` table where scope is `website` and scope_id is 8.
Maybe a website you had and got deleted or you somehow inserted a wrong value in the table.
Look for these occurrences and delete them.

Comment: I have checked there is no entry with website and scope_id 8